# ruamel.yaml and yamllint conflict on sequence indentation

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I have the following YAML:

```yaml
root:
  - foo:
    - bar: 1
    - baz: 2
```

When I read/dump with `ruamel.yaml` (and `offset=2, sequence=4` config), I get the following result:

```yaml
root:
  - foo:
      - bar: 1
      - baz: 2
```

It's **not ideal**, but I guess this is how `ruamel.yaml` works and there's no way to change it (I would prefer to have the same output as the input; if it's possible that would be the best).

Anyway, the problem is when I run `yamllint` and I get:

> error    wrong indentation: expected 4 but found 6  (indentation)

I guess it's because Python's `yaml` parser starts counting from right under the parent hyphen, and `ruamel.yaml` doesn't.

Any idea how to make them both work?

I tried to play with `yamllint` config but had no luck.

Comment: Why aren't you simply using `offset=2, sequence=2`?

Comment: It leads to even less ideal result in other cases (IIRC there's an example on ruamel docs why it's not recommended).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always need a value for `sequence` (assume that this is short for sequence-indent) that is at least two more than the offset. Two, because two positions are needed: one for the (block) sequence indicator character (`-`) and the following necessary space.

When you have a block sequence that is a value for a mapping key 'xyz' then you can forego the normally necessary indentation and align the sequence indicators with the first character of the key:

```
xyz:
- 1
- 2
```

That is what ruamel yaml defaults to and which is also what you get with `sequence=2` and `offset=0`.

Your original is inconsistently indented. The value for key `root` is a block sequence that is sequence-indented `4` with an offset of `2`. However the value for key  `foo` is sequence-indented `2` with an offset of `0`. That is something you cannot generate with `ruamel.yaml` as it doesn't allow you to specify different indent values for values of different keys thereby making indentation consistent.

The result that you get is correct for `sequence=4, offset=2` as the `f` from `foo` starts 4 positions after the `r` from `root` and the `b` from `bar` also 4 positions after the `f` from foo.

If you had used the default or specified `sequence=2, offset=0` you would get the (equally consistent):

```
root:
- foo:
  - bar: 1
  - baz: 2
```

(`foo` has moved 2 positions left and `bar` 4 positions (2 for itself and two because the whole sequence that is the value for `root` moved 2).

I don't know how yamllint works, but if you get that error from the four line example result, then it is clear that it gets the 4 from counting from `r' from root to` f`of foo and then starts counting for the`b`from bar starting at the`-`before`foo`(instead of at the`f` of foo. This is IMO incorrect.

You could try and see what `yamllint` does if you give it my example above. Since both indents there have been reduced by 2, it should complain:

> error wrong indentation: expected 2 but found 4 (indentation)

If it doesn't complain, use that setting for `ruamel.yaml`. If it doesn't or if it accepts both your original and my `sequence=2, offset=0` example, you should probably try and find a more consistent linting tool for YAML.